# Computer monitor shuts off temporarily when the window AC kicks on

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, power-supply, power

When my window AC kicks on, one of my two monitors kicks off for a couple seconds. It's never the same monitor when it happens. I installed a very large UPS thinking it was power drops, but it doesn't help at all. Any other suggestions?

Comment: When my window AC kicks on,   ... What does this mean to you?  To me, it says you are starting the computer and the monitors reset.

Comment: The opposite monitor would still be on and fully functional when this happens, mouse and everything.

Comment: Is the UPS a "continuous conversion" or a normal pass-trough?

Comment: Dont know. How do I find that out? Its a Cyberpower 1500 AVR with voltage regulation. I have the monitors and tower on the battery backup.

Comment: Please answer the first comment.

Comment: My guess?  1) You are running a low amperage circuit breaker and the power gets pulled when the AC kicks on (I too see this in my house as my lights dim..). 2)  The Cyberpower 1500 AVR [Isn't doing its job](https://www.amazon.com/product-reviews/B000FBK3QK/ref=acr_dp_hist_1?ie=UTF8&filterByStar=one_star&reviewerType=all_reviews#reviews-filter-bar) as seen in the negative reviews on this product.  I know.. I know.. negative reviews against positive ones are not always reliable but I am guessing from what I am reading that these negative reviews are on the money.

Comment: You guys really do just have the worst spec mains electricity in the world, don't you? [I'm joking… but I'm not] I've never heard of such a thing happening, ever. Switching on one device causes a noticeable power drop in another??? I can run, for comparison, a 4KW 14,000 BTU air-con from anywhere on the same ring as all the computers [i.e. on the same breaker] without ever seeing anything like that.

Comment: @Tetsujin The problem is huge homes, loads far away from source and wires designed for minimum requirements.  Increase the cross-sectional area of wires and you would have no problem.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat - if you have long runs, why design for minimum requirements? Why not sensibly design for maximum?

Comment: @Tetsujin  They should, but they are maximizing their profits.  You have big homes which esparate the proble.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat - there should be no "should". It should be buiding regs. If it's not, then of course they'll do it on the cheap. That's why I made my comment in the first place. The system is just hokey. Single phase & what seems to be a kind of dual phase to give 2 different voltages & a multitude of un-earthed sockets. It's just the worst spec.

Comment: It is not the regs or the designers directly, but users who plug in 1kW computers on 1.8kW lines.  A home built before the 1980's or even the 2000's can be up to code, but can not compete with today's tower PC's with multiple monitors.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat - see… you have 1.8KW lines!! Minimum spec here is ≅3KW, 13A @ 240V, on rings not spurs, so they don't ever get hot. Max domestic spec is 50A, still single-phase 240V, only really used for electric power-showers [up to 11KW] these days. Most things including ovens, a/c etc will run off standard 13A.

Comment: @Tetsujin 15A & 20A @ 120V and 30A @ 208V or 240V (depending on transformers) for residential.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat - too many standards, different plugs for each, or things go bang. vs… One standard with one plug. Showers don't have plugs. Everything else will go in the same socket. Sockets are all compulsorily earthed.

Answer (score 1):

The voltage is dipping when your air conditioner kicks in.  This will happen if your PC and/or AC is a long distance from your breaker panel AND they are on the same circuit.  On start up, the AC is drawing more current which means the voltage drop to the wire or I2R losses goes up decreasing voltage at load and hence the monitor shuts down.

From [Fundamentals of Electricity - Voltage Drop - Definition](https://c03.apogee.net/mvc/home/hes/land/el?utilityname=citizenselectric&spc=foe&id=4578)

[image]

Without knowing the info on your UPS, but I'd guess the voltage never goes away so your UPS does not kick in.

The true solution is thicker wires and/or separate wires to the air conditioner and the computer.  That is not realistic for most users.

Alternatively, the air conditioner and the computer must be on different circuits.  Move your computer to different outlets in your home and see if this impacts the problem.  All outlets in the same room are typically on the same circuit.  But if another outlet is closer to the breaker box, the impact of AC starting will be less.  Extension cords will make the problem worse.

You do need to investigate the problem a bit more.  This info should help.

If moving the computer has an impact on the problem, then the problem is voltage dip and you can select a solution to fix the problem.  Options for solutions are outlined in: [Case Study: Choosing among Voltage-dip-compensation Devices on the Market](https://www.clp.com.hk/en/my-business-site/business-advice-site/power-quality-service-site/power-quality-information-site/Documents/Case%20Study%20Nov%202012%20Eng%20(Final).pdf).

Comment: OMG!  Nice answer to balance my comment :) !!! +1  Such a detailed explanation.  Also.. (for the OP).. like the answer says.. try to understand what outlets are connected to what line to the breaker.  Just moving the cord will likely put you on the same circuit breaker so you need to figure out what outlets are on a different breaker switch.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I couldn't fit it in a comment!

Comment: Oh.. one trick I use it to use a high wattage (incandescent) light bulb plugged in to the system when it kicks on.  You will see it dim.  You could also use a multi-meter if you have one and know how to use it.

Comment: I appreciate the help, but why would one monitor do that and not the other one? They are both plugged into the UPS. Ive had the power stop in an outage and the whole computer kept going as it should. So is it the voltage regulation part that isn't working correctly?

Comment: No idea.  I have a test setup with dual monitors and both go out when a small fridge on same circuit kicks in.  I live with it and I know how to fix it without a UPS.  I don't know your setup, so any other info is pure guesswork.

Comment: As I said in the answer, move your computer to different outlets with and without UPS and see what impact that has.